# OpenSSL encrypt and decrypt between RHEL version

Tags: linux, rhel, openssl

I am currently using the below command to encrypt & decrypt in RHEL 6. But I have pool of servers which contains RHEL 6 & 8, so the encryption may happen on RHEL6 node but the decryption might go RHEL8 node.

Without changing the way the encryption is happening currently in RHEL6, is there a way to decrypt the same in RHEL8 and vice versa.

Commands in use currently:

ENCRYPTION:

```bash
echo $passcode | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -kfile /root/kfile -md sha256 | base64 -w 0
```

DECRYPTION:

```bash
echo $pcode | base64 -w 0 -d | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -kfile /root/kfile -md sha256
```

Comment: Sholud be no problem caused by RHEL6-RHEL8, `openssl` is a program, and Linux is Linux. I have not analyzed your method.